# Detele row from a table based of the time of insertion

Tags: hibernate, hql

Is there any way, using *Hibernate* *HQL* delete for example 3 oldest rows which contain colomn type *TIMESTAMP* with time of insertion of row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can create a query to obtain the 3 oldest records in your `YourTable` table:

```
String hql1 = "select t.time from YourTable t order by t.time asc";
Query query1 = session.createQuery(hql1);
query1.setMaxResults(3);
List results = query1.list();
```

Next, do an HQL query to delete all records matching these 3 timestamps:

```
String hql2 = string.Format("delete from YourTable t WHERE t.time IN ({0})",
                            string.Join(",", results.ToArray()));
Query query2 = session.createQuery(hql2);
int result = query2.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Number of row deleted: " + result);
```

This answer assumes that your table class is called `YourTable`, which has a field (column) called `time`.  It also assumes that each timestamp is unique, which may not be the case.  If your timestamps are not guaranteed to be unique, then you would want to delete using a primary key instead.

Comment: @PetrF. Have you tested this code in your setup to make sure that it meets your needs?

Comment: Why not a simple delete query?